# The number of irrational roots of $(x^2 -3x +1)(x^2 +3x +2)(x^2 -9x + 20) = -30$ is___?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

> > The number of irrational roots of $(x^2 -3x +1)(x^2 +3x +2)(x^2 -9x + 20) = -30$ is___?

---

My Approach :

Multiplying the above equation and then apply Descartis rule is very lengthy method. Also I tried it by taking factors of $30$ and then solving the equation but that is also going very lengthy .

Please suggest some good method of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good method for your question, but we have
$$(x^2-3x+1)(x+1)(x+2)(x-4)(x-5)=-30$$
rearranging
$$(x^2-3x+1)(x+1)(x-4)(x+2)(x-5)=-30$$
$$(t+1)(t-4)(t-10)=-30$$
where $t=x^2-3x$.

Now, one sees that $t=5$ works. So, 
$$(t+1)(t-4)(t-10)+30$$
is divisible by $t-5$ to have
$$(t+1)(t-4)(t-10)+30=(t-5)(t^2-8t-14)$$
So,
$$x^2-3x=t=5,4\pm\sqrt{30}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that the polynomial is a sixth degree monic polynomial whose constant term is $70$. Hence, by [rational roots theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the possible roots can only be divisors of $70$. You will find that none of the roots are rational.

Comment: None of the roots of $x^2+1=0$ are rational either, but that doesn't mean they're irrational, does it?